# Visual Studio 2010 horribly slow on a huge C++ project when ++ icon is animated

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VS 2010: What is the ++ file symbol on the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259854/vs-2010-what-is-the-file-symbol-on-the-status-bar)

Every time I open Tortoise SVN project (lots of code) in Visual Studio 2010 it will suddenly start doing something that leads to my HDD actively working and this leads to my computer (and VS as well) getting super luggish. I noticed there's a "++" icon near main windows bottom right next to line number and column number:

[image: strange ++ icon]

that is almost always animated at the times I see the slowdown.

What's that icon for? How can I disable or make more friendly the activity that slows my computer down?

Comment: Probably updating the Intellisense database.  Do you have any plugins installed (especially VA-X)?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No special plugins. VS 2008 would load much bigger projects no problem.

Comment: I seem to have asked essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259854/vs-2010-what-is-the-file-symbol-on-the-status-bar

Comment: And I have the same issue: it appears in my largish project, and makes it very sluggish with pauses as long as 20 seconds while it's doing its disk-intensive "whatever"

Comment: Are you sure that this problem is related to Visual Studio? I have similar experience and I found out that Tortoise SVN is updating the Icons (MANY) which slow down the PC

Comment: @dip: I indeed have Tortoise SVN installed and still I noticed very strong correlation specifically between that animated icon appearing and the horrible slowdown.

Comment: @sharptooth You can try to modify the TortoiseSVN settings on Icon Overlays. I usually define the "include" and "exclude" paths and apply some settings accordingly, e.g. Checked "Show overlays only in explorer"

Answer (score -1):

1. Open up Task Manager (or better yet Process Explorer).
2. Under the View menu add columns for I/O Reads
3. Sort by that column
4. Open your Tortoise SVN project
5. Watch what process is changing the most

I've seen both Intellisense and Tortoise SVN both slow things down a bunch as the commenters above have suggested.